# Bigquery: manage service accounts

Tags: google-bigquery

In what scenario that we need multiple service accounts or multiple keys under one service accounts?
I mean, is there any constraints or considerations from the bigquery side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigquery does not restrict the number of service account credentials you can use. I don't know what the limit is for the number of service accounts you are allowed to create in a Google Apis Console project, but if you can create service account credentials, you can use them with Bigquery.

You do need to give your service accounts access to your datasets and the project itself in order to run queries. The easiest way to do this is to add your service account to your project's Permissions page. How project "roles" map to Bigquery access is described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/access-control#projectroles